# How to split number using a separator in java

Tags: java

i have an input  in a file where i have some numbers in the format

106,648|403,481
747,826|369,456
758,122|365,637
503,576|808,710
325,374|402,513

not i want to format the number as 
106,648
403,481
747,826
.. 
and so on  but  i  am unable to do this i have done this so  far

```
public class MidPointSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file=new File("D:/midpoint.txt");

    try{

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);

            while(sc.hasNext()){

                String value=sc.next();

                String getVal[]=value.split("|");
                for(int i=0;i<getVal.length;i++){

                    System.out.println(getVal[i]);
                }

            }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File is not Found");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Another Exception");
    }

}
```

but i am not getting the desired output.Please someone help me ..

Comment: while splitting try to escape the pipe character. as `.split("\|");`

Comment: i also want the sum of the y coordinates in  this pair ...can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a regex metacharacter and it needs to be escaped, try `"\\|"`

Answer (score 2):

Java's split uses a regex, so you need to double escape pipe:

```
String[] getVal=value.split("\\|");
```

If it were a plain regex you'd need to escape it anyway, but in java `"\"` is a [special character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657864/java-regexp-patterns-have-double-backslashes-how-to-store-patterns-in-readable), due to characters like `\t` and `\n`, hence the double escape.